# How Compose functions update themselves?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Lets suppose we have this compose function:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val foobar = remember { mutableStateOf("Foo") }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        delay(2000)
        foobar.value = "Bar"
    }
    Text(text = foobar.value)
}
```

`foobar` state changes after 2 seconds, `test` function is recalled after `foobar` value has been changed (recomposition).
How can this be achieved? I mean how to recall/notify a function that one of its variables has been changed?

Comment: It isn't clear exacty what you want. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Comment: If you're asking how to do the same with non `Composable` function of your own, that's for sure is a very hard task, I'd start with checking on Compose source code.

Comment: Yes! I want to recreate the same mechanism on functions of my own, i just found how Compose runtime work under the hood [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BRlI5zfCCk) and i think i understand now a little how it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.